# Give a C++  class foo, inside, it has a synchronized method. How to guarantee the synchronized method being accessed by only one thread

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, class, synchronization

Give a C++ class foo, inside, it has a synchronized method. We have two 
objects of foo, called, f1 and f2, if f1 and f2 are concurrently running, 
can we guarantee the synchronized method being accessed by only one thread?

My idea:

Use a mutex, whoever needs to access the method, who get the mutex.

This interview question seems not to be so simple.

Any solutions ?

thanks

Comment: The first two ways I can think of are to use a static synchronized method or to use a mutex like you said.

Comment: Are you asking how to guarantee access by only one thread *at a time*, or only one thread *during the lifetime of the process*?

Answer (score 8):

In java, unless the method is static, you need to synchronize externally in order to ensure the method is only called by one thread at one time.

You can also synchronize the method itself on a static variable of the class.  E.g.

```
public class myClass
{
  private static Object myLock = new Object();

  public void myMethod()
  {
    synchronized(myLock)
    {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With a static method you'd do the following in Java:

```
class Foo {

   public static synchronized void mymethod() {
      ...
   }
}
```

You actually synchronize on `Foo.class` in this case.

If you have an instance method (i.e. non-static) and you need to synchronize, you could put a `synchronized` block into the method and synchronize on any object even on the class itself:

```
public void mymethod() {
  synchronized( Foo.class ) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Note that this would synchronize access to other static synchronized methods in the same class du to the shared lock object `Foo.class`.

Btw, the answer to that question depends on the definition of *accessed*: Multiple threads can *access* the method by trying to invoke it, read its reflection metadata  or even enter it in case of nested synchronized blocks but they would normally not *execute* it concurrently unless parts of the method are not synchronized (or synchronized on a different lock object).

Comment: This only works if the class is loaded by only one class loader. If two class loaders load the same class, the methods in the two class instances will be synchronizing on different objects. They could then execute simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly and you want it synchronized across all instances make the method static synchronized

Answer (score 0):

If you have two different instances of class `foo`, then it does not matter what happens because each has a different copy of the method and the synchronization happens on the `this` object:

```
public synchronized void method() {
    // code
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
public void method() {
   synchronized(this) {
      // code
   }
}
```

Having said this, if each thread calls `method` from a different instance of `foo`:

1. they will acquire different locks
2. they will not produce any data race if you are not modifying data outside of class `foo`